# EF Core 3.0 .Include() chain taking ~5-10x longer than 2.2

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm having trouble with a large EF Core query that has a lot of chained `.Include()`. 
I have a linq query that looks like this:

```cs
_context.Equipment.Include(x => x.Group)
                .Include(x => x.Status)
                .Include(x => x.Area)
                .Include(x => x.EquipmentType)
                .Include(x => x.Parts).ThenInclude(x => x.ChildrenParts)
                .Include(x => x.Parts).ThenInclude(x => x.ParentParts)
                .Include(x => x.Parts).ThenInclude(x => x.Vendor)
                .Include(x => x.Notes)
                .Include(x => x.Department)
                .Include(x => x.PMaintenance)
                .Include(x => x.SystemInfo).ThenInclude(x => x.SystemUsers)
                .Include(x => x.SystemInfo).ThenInclude(x => x.Frameworks)
                .Include(x => x.SystemInfo).ThenInclude(x => x.VideoCards)
                .Include(x => x.SystemInfo).ThenInclude(x => x.StorageDrives)
                .Include(x => x.SystemInfo).ThenInclude(x => x.Software)
                .Include(x => x.SystemInfo).ThenInclude(x => x.NetworkAdapters)
                .Include(x => x.SystemInfo).ThenInclude(x => x.Printers)
                .Include(x => x.MaintenanceHours)
                .Include(x => x.Attachments)
                .Include(x => x.Request)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EquipmentId == id);
```

In EF Core 2.2, this took less than a few seconds to evaluate. Now on EF Core 3.0, it takes about 15 seconds to complete. What about EF Core 3 made this so slow? I read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#single-sql-statement-per-linq-query) that ef now creates one sql statement per linq query, but I don't see how the statement would have changed in this instance. Can I do something to this query that would decrease the execution time?

**EDIT:** This is on SQL Server v11.0.3

Comment: Why do you need so many includes? Why not just select the values you need?

Comment: I need all of this to display on the Details page.

Comment: Why not just call into a view with all the fields?

Comment: @TonyAbrams I'm not sure I understand what you're referring to. 
**Edit** OH! A database view. I'm not familiar with views and EF.

Comment: It'd probably be worth inspecting the SQL query generated between the different EF versions, to see if anything actually changed there

Comment: Wow, that's a **lot** of includes. Any time you are doing something like this, you need to ask yourself if there's a better way.

Comment: I could cache all of these entities and update them on an interval, but the thing is this wasn't an issue on 2.2.

Comment: Wow, I've missed that "Singe SQL per LINQ query" thing. If that's true (as it seems), that should explain the difference in performance with EFC 2.x which uses 1 separate SQL query per each collection Include. Removing client evaluation was great, but this is just... awful. Post it to their issue tracker and see their response.

Comment: @IvanStoev Looks like there is already [an issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18022) about this!

Comment: @aweyeahdawg Yeah, as well as [Discuss cartesian explosion and discuss workarounds #1769](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/1769) and [20x slowdown in gigantic query after updating to EF Core 3 compared to 2.2 #18017](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18017). Too bad :-(

Comment: One solution could be to ask to the EF Plus team on their site to bring back the IncludeOptimized feature (Well that's me..): https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus  ...Also, you will be able to add filter in your include. We never added this feature for EF Core since the v2.x was working exactly like us. However, it seems they are now using the same behavior as EF6 for EF Core 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this. You might need to change some of the "Select" and "SelectMany" options and the Id field names as you did not post the context.`

```
var query = _context.Equipment.Include(x => x.Group)
            .Include(x => x.Status)
            .Include(x => x.Area)
            .Include(x => x.EquipmentType)
            .Include(x => x.Notes)
            .Include(x => x.Department)
            .Include(x => x.PMaintenance)
            .Include(x => x.MaintenanceHours)
            .Include(x => x.Attachments)
            .Include(x => x.Request).FirstOrDefault(x => x.EquipmentId == id);

            query.Include(x => x.Parts).ThenInclude(x => x.ChildrenParts).SelectMany(x => x.Parts).Where(a => query.Select(q => q.PartsId).Contains(a.Id)).Load();
            query.SelectMany(x => x.Parts).SelectMany(x => x.ChildrenParts).Load();
            query.SelectMany(x => x.Parts).SelectMany(x => x.ParentParts).Load();
            query.SelectMany(x => x.Parts).Select(x => x.Vendor).Load();
            query.Include(x => x.SystemInfo).ThenInclude(x => x.SystemUsers).SelectMany(x => x.SystemInfo).Where(a => query.Select(q => q.SystemInfoId).Contains(a.Id)).Load();
            query.SelectMany(x => x.SystemInfo).SelectMany(x => x.Frameworks).Load();
            query.SelectMany(x => x.SystemInfo).SelectMany(x => x.VideoCards).Load();
            query.SelectMany(x => x.SystemInfo).SelectMany(x => x.StorageDrives).Load();
            query.SelectMany(x => x.SystemInfo).SelectMany(x => x.Software).Load();
            query.SelectMany(x => x.SystemInfo).SelectMany(x => x.NetworkAdapters).Load();
            query.SelectMany(x => x.SystemInfo).SelectMany(x => x.Printers).Load();

            query.ToList();
```

Hope this helps.